# How can I show elements one by one on scroll while making the line element grow 90% of its container?

Tags: jquery, animation, gsap, scrolltrigger

as mentioned in title I want to show the elements one by one on screen on scroll while make line element grow vertically like a roadmap kinda view. And also I need to add active class to milestone-stone element so that it indicates the active element and give it a cool effect.
I have used gsap for this but couldn't figure it out myself.

```
$(function () {
  var expandDiv = document.getElementById("line-span");
  var speed = 10;
  function expanding() {
    var scrolltop = window.pageYOffset;
    var scrollAndSpeed = scrolltop / speed;
    expandDiv.style.height = Math.min(Math.max(scrollAndSpeed, 10), 90) + "%";
  }
  window.addEventListener(
    "scroll",
    function () {
      requestAnimationFrame(expanding);
    },
    false
  );
  const milestones = $(".milestone");
  milestones.css({ opacity: 0, transform: "translateY(50px)" });
  milestones.each(function (index, element) {
    gsap.to(element, {
      opacity: 1,
      y: 0,
      duration: 0.2,
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: element,
        start: "100% 50%", // Adjust the start position as needed
        end: "100% 50%", // Adjust the end position as needed
        toggleActions: "play none play reverse",
        markers: true,
        scrub: true,
      },
    });
  });
});
```

Here is my Codepen link: https://codepen.io/Xteripus/pen/RwqJepY

Thanks a lot in advance.